# Nginx+uWsgi+Flask cannot setup success

Tags: python, linux, nginx, uwsgi

I want use nginx, uWsgi, Flask on centos 5, but always has some error.

3 app are all newest version, the uwgsi_params file copy from uwsgi/nginx.

I use virtualenv to config python env.

```
project path: /path/to/project
virtualevn: /path/to/virenv/pyenv27
```

***First step:***

I use nginx and uWsgi, and browse show error page:

```
uWSGI Error
wsgi application not found
```

**Nginx config:**

```
location / {
      uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:5555;
      uwsgi_param UWSGI_PYHOME /path/to/virenv/pyenv27;
      uwsgi_param UWSGI_CHDIR /path/to/project;
      uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT uwsgi;
      uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME "";

      include uwsgi_params;

}
```

**Flask file is simple:**

```
import sys
sys.path.append(sys.path[0])

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return "Hello World!"


#app.config.from_pyfile('product.cfg')

def application(environ, start_response):
    return app(environ, start_response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**uWsgi command:**

```
/opt/uwsgi -s 127.0.0.1:5555 -M 4 -t 30 -A 4 -p 4 -d /var/log/uwsgi.log --pidfile /var/run/uwsgi.pid --no-site --vhost --limit-as 256
```

---

***2 Step***

I use uWsgi only.

cmd：

```
/opt/uwsgi/uwsgi --xml /path/to/project/uwsgi.xml
```

but I got error:

```
ImportError: No module named site
```

uWsgi xml:

```
<uwsgi>
<chdir>/path/to/project/</chdir>
<pythonpath>/path/to/project</pythonpath>
<virtualenv>/path/to/virenv/pyenv27</virtualenv>

<wsgi-file>/path/to/project/uwsgi.py</wsgi-file>


<callable>app</callable>

<socket>:6000</socket>
<chmod-socket>666</chmod-socket>

<master />
<processes>1</processes>
<uid>uwsgi</uid>
<gid>uwsgi</gid>

<disable-logging>false</disable-logging><!-- Errors are still logged; this just disables request logging which Cherokee takes care of -->
<daemonize>/path/to/project/uwsgi.log</daemonize>
<vacuum />
<no-orphans />
</uwsgi>
```

Is there something wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

In your command-line version, you have:

```
/opt/uwsgi -s 127.0.0.1:5555 --no-site
```

But in your xml version, you are missing an equivalent `no-site` option:

```
<uwsgi>
<no-site>true</no-site>
</uwsgi>
```

so it's trying to load the Python `site.py` file. You could also add an empty file, but I'd go with the xml option. And

```
<no-site />
```

is also valid syntax, I tend to use the *true* flag, myself.